# Lebesgue conduct integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, convolution

I. Suppose $f\in \mathcal{L^1}(R^n),g\in \mathcal{L^1}(R^n)$, then conduct integral $f*g$ is defined as $f*g(x)= \int_{R^n}f(x-y)g(y)dy$ for all $x$.

My task is to prove following statements.

(1) $f*g \in \mathcal{L^1}( R^n)$;

(2) When $g \in \mathcal{C}_0^1(R^n)$, 
then $f*g \in \mathcal{C}^1(R^n)$.

II. $\mathcal{L}^1(R)$ stands for the family of all Lebesgue integrable functions on $R$.

Let 
$ \hat{f}(\xi)=\int_R e^{-ix\xi}f(x)dx $
for $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(R)$. Answer the following questions:

(1) Show that $\hat{f}(\xi)$ is a bounded continuous function on $R$.

(2) Let $(f*g)(x)=\int_R f(x-y)g(y)dy $ for $f,g\in \mathcal{L}^1(R)$. Show that $f*g\in\mathcal{L}^1(R)$.

(3) Show that $\hat{f*g}=\hat{f}\hat{g}$ for $f,g\in \mathcal{L}^1(R)$.

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: prove $f*g$ is $L^1$ function on $R^n$

Comment: Definition of $\mathcal{L}^1(R)$: $\int_R|f(x)|dx <\infty$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** start considering the integral $\int_{[-R,R]}|f*g(x)|dx$, and notice that this can be bounded by $\int_{[-R,R]}\int_{\Bbb R}|f(x-y)g(y)|dydx$. Now use Fubini-Tonelli's theorem for non-negative functions in order to switch the integrals.

For the other part, you can use dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Could you explain more details?

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: For I(1) to prove $f∗g\in\mathcal{L}^1(R^n)$, then to prove $\int_R^n |f(x-y)g(y)|dy<\infty$. then for I(2) $f*g\in \mathcal{C}^1(R^n)$, using dominated convergence theorem?

Answer (score 0):

For II(2), it is same as I(1).
And for $(1)$, $e^{-ix\xi}\le 2$, then I can prove $\hat{f}\le \int_R 2f(x)dx<\infty$, then it is bounded. As to continuous?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the meaning of the assertion that $e^{-ix\xi}\le 2$?

Comment: $e^{-ix\xi}=cos(-x\xi)+isin(x\xi)$, $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: And so what? Why is this $\leqslant2$? (Your formula has some sign problems but let us forget it.)

Comment: $|cos(-x\xi)|\le 1$ and $|isin(-x\xi)|\le 1$ then have $\le 2$.Correct?

Comment: No, not correct. Why did you add some $|\ |$? They were not in your original statement... So what do you claim is $\leqslant2$ exactly?

Comment: If remove the $||$, the conclusion is same. Anyway the max $cos(-x\xi)+isin(-x\xi) \le 2$.

Comment: No, not the same, in fact it becomes absurd. Say, do you think that $i\leqslant1$ or that $i\geqslant1$?

Comment: You miss something. Here i is $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: No I do not, I am just trying to show you that there is a serious problem with your argument. You state that $\cos(-x\xi)+i\sin(-x\xi)\leqslant2$. For $x\xi=-\pi/2$, this means that $i\leqslant2$. For $x\xi=\pi/2$, this means that $-i\leqslant2$. Do you really believe that $-2\leqslant i\leqslant2$? If yes, why? If not, why?